# How to clone a git repository without association with git using gitpython?

Tags: python, git, shutil, gitpython

When I clone the repository using the following code the repository gets cloned into local but it is also associated with GIT.

```
from git import Repo
Repo.clone_from(url, path)
```

And If I want to remove the directory using the following

```
shutil.rmtree(path)
```

I get the permission error. I'm looking for either a way to remove the directory even if it is associated with git or clone it into local without being associated with git in the first place. Later one is a preferred approach if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "associated with Git"? Can you show the exact error? And what operating system are you using?

Comment: I think that's specific to your system, I tried that before and tried it now, it works perfectly no permission error

Comment: @Schwern - A green tick mark appears on the cloned repository and the .git folder is present in the repo. When I delete it and try to run `shutil.rmtree(path)` it works. I'm using windows

Comment: @RaviKumar A green tick mark in what?

Answer (score 0):

Windows will not allow you to delete a file or directory if something has it open. [You mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110447/how-to-clone-a-git-repository-without-association-with-git-using-gitpython?noredirect=1#comment108112624_61110447) "*A green tick mark appears on the cloned repository*"; I expect you have an application which is holding the .git directory open. Close that application, then I expect it will work.

Comment: I do not have anything open. But Still I get the error.

Comment: A green tick mark on each file and folder within the git repository. I deleted the .git folder within git repository and then tried `shutil.rmtree(path)` it worked

Comment: @RaviKumar I do not understand what is displaying a green tick mark or what the significance of a green tick mark is. I suspect you have a 3rd party Git tool installed. I'd need to see a screenshot to help.

Answer (score 0):

As @Schwern said, you must have Git installed in your PATH, so if in your terminal the command `git` returns an error, the Python script won't work.
And as said by @Schwern too, a programm is using your directory, and the "green tick" make me think that your OneDrive is synchronizing the folder to their servers, that's why you can't delete it. (and OneDrive synchronisation is automatic, even if OneDrive is "not open in a window") Try to disable OneDrive for some folders where you do stuff that does not need to be synchronized, or (I dont know if its possible) disable synchronization for hidden folders.